# SQL - Group results by time interval

Tags: sql, time, frame, sql-server-2012, intervals

With the given table structure (`eventTime` is in seconds) I want to group the results by a given time frame:

For example: 5 minutes

```
0 to 5:   1 
5 to 10:  2
10 to 15: 3
.....
```

How can this be done in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks!

Florian

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[evalHubSupply](
[evalHubSupplyId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[projectId] [int] NOT NULL,
[scenarioId] [int] NOT NULL,
[iterationId] [int] NOT NULL,
[evalExportId] [int] NOT NULL,
[eventType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[eventTime] [int] NOT NULL,
[stopId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[stopName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[vehicleId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[transitLineId] [varchar](50) NULL,
[transitRouteId] [varchar](50) NULL,
[capacity] [int] NULL,
[arrivalTimeAtStop] [int] NULL,
[agentsOnBoard] [int] NULL)
```

Sample data (interval 1 hour):

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/481455/table_data.xlsx
or
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/481455/table_data_open.ods

The tab "Table data" contains sample data from evalHubSupply. 
The column "Time interval" calculates the interval (in this case per hour), to which the eventTime relates. The results tabs counts how many events are related to a specific interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will give number of records in every 5 min group

```
select eventTime/5,count(*)
from   evalHubSupply
group by eventTime/5
```

Comment: Hi, I need to group the results by eventTime(s), which fall into a specific time frame (0 to 5, 5 to 10,...). Your solutions groups the results by hitting the specific time - my eventTimes are unique, therefore I get one result row per event record.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your requirement.. could u plz update your question with give sample data

Comment: Hey, sorry your answer is completly correct. It's just necessary to round eventTime/XX and now everything is fine. Thanks!